# validator w3.org menu warning for html5

Tags: html, menu, validation, standards-compliance

I have a warning on use of a menu tag in an html5 document. 
using http://validator.w3.org

> The menu element is not supported by browsers yet. It would probably
>   be better to wait for implementations

```
<menu>  
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home_button.jpg" alt="Home" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="research.htm"><img src="images/research_button.jpg" alt="Research" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="publ.htm"><img src="images/publs_button.jpg" alt="Publications" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="researchz.htm"><img src="images/researchz_button.jpg" alt="Researchers" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="presentations.htm"><img src="images/presentations.jpg" alt="Presentations, Posters, and Talks" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="colabs.htm"><img src="images/collab_button.jpg" alt="Collaborators" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="classes.htm"><img src="images/courses_button.jpg" alt="Courses" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.htm"><img src="images/gallery_button.jpg" alt="gallery" ></a></li> 
</menu>
```

Is there any reason i shouldn't use this code to serve as my menu bar?
Also, when will it be implemented? is there a release date?

Comment: accidentally submitted before complete

Comment: You don't understand the warning?  It precisely answers your question.  ***"The menu element is not supported by browsers yet."***  ~ What don't you understand about "not supported"?

Comment: @j0h a good read for you if you keep giving to much importance to validators: http://zurb.com/article/1260/we-ve-moved-beyond-code-validators

Comment: @balexandre, that's an opinion piece and has no place here since it's likely to spark a debate within comments about wether or not code should follow compliance standards.

Comment: `<menu>` tags are not meant for navigation anyways.

Comment: The zurb blog post is comforting

Comment: Li elements are allowed to be descendants of menu?  Looks like invalid markup to me.

Comment: @cimmanon, looks wrong to me too, [but apparently that's valid markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

Comment: OP, the "accepted" answer fails to tackle your last two questions: _"... when will it be implemented? is there a release date?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<menu>` tag is NOT supported by any of the major browsers.

Comment: really? because I just tried <nav>, and the validator told me to use menu instead.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_menu.asp

Comment: In HTML5, `<nav>` is correct, I use it.

Comment: Please don't link to disreptuable sites (see: http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: What's happened to SO... when an accepted answer is practically an identical copy of the error message already posted in the OP.  What did the OP learn here... how to read?

Comment: @cimmanon That's funny. I've used the site for years and it's been VERY helpful.

Comment: This isn't a joke, continuing to post references to w3schools will not win you any fans.

Comment: @cimmanon Yeah and I'm not joking, w3schools has been very helpful for me so I will continue to use it.